# Error in Rmarkdown everytime I run a code chunk

Tags: r-markdown

I have created an R document that knits to pdf. It starts like this:

```
title: "title"
author: "abcd"
date: "29/03/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

#Question 1
##Part 1
```

Every time I run a code chunk, it works but I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(parse_only(paste("alist(", quote_label(params), ")"))) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In eval(parse_only(paste("alist(", quote_label(params), ")"))) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

I am not sure what this means and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you just render it to html?

```
---
title: "title"
author: "abcd"
date: "29/03/2021"
output: html_document
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

#Question 1
##Part 1
```

You might be having issues with Pandoc try:
`install.packages("rmarkdown", dep = TRUE)` and
`install.packages("tinytex")` to reinstall pandoc and latex